# Which index would be used if there are multiple indexes containing the same fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

Take, for example, a `find()` that involves a field `a` and `b`, in that order. For example,

```
db.collection.find({'a':{'$lt':10},'b':{'$lt':5}})
```

I have two keys in my array of indexes for the collection:

```
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "x.test",
    "name" : "a_1_b_1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 1,
        "c" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "x.test",
    "name" : "a_1_b_1_c_1"
}
]
```

Is it **guaranteed** that mongo will use the first key since it more accurately matches the query, or does it randomly choose any of the two keys because they will both work?

Comment: can show us your indexes?

Comment: Updated my question with the actual array (didn't think it was necessary earlier)

Comment: It's worth noting that you can drop your first index (`a_1_b_1`) since it is a proper subset of the second index (same keys and order) which can be used to satisfy the same queries. Duplicate indexes are unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Yup, this was just more of a theoretical question of how MongoDB works though. I realize this would make writes slower etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB has a query optimizer which selects the indexes that are most efficient. From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#read-operations-query-optimization):

> The MongoDB query optimizer processes queries and chooses the most
>   efficient query plan for a query given the available indexes.

So it's not strictly guaranteed (but I expect that the smaller index will yield results faster than the bigger compound index). 
You can also use [hint](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) operator to force the query optimizer to use the specified index.

```
db.collection.find({'a':{'$lt':10},'b':{'$lt':5}}).hint({a:1, b:1});
```

However, those two indexes in your example are redundant. That's because the compound index supports queries on any [prefix of index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) fields.

The following index:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1});
```

Can support queries that include `a`, `a` and `b` and `a` and `b` and `c`, but *not* only `b` or `c`, or only `b` and `c`.

Comment: Yup, I realize the redundancy... I was just curious that **IF** both were present, what would be chosen (which you answered).

Answer (score 0):

You and use $exist,, When  is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the field, including documents where the field value is null. If  is false, the query returns only the documents that do not contain the field.

[$exist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

the query will be

```
db.inventory.find( { "key.a": { $exists: true, 1 },"key.b": { $exists: true, 1 }  } )
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question (or I your answer)... I want to know which index will be used... the one with the first key or the one with the second key, in the situation where either would be possible in a `find` or `sort` command being executed.

Comment: The `key` is a field within the array of indexes a collection has. Like when I say `db.collection.ensureIndex({a:1,b:1})`

Comment: the key is array or json document.. of collection?

Comment: it is a part of the output of `db.collection.getIndexes()`